# nodejs page did't stop reloading

Tags: node.js

I created this code to insert data to database using nodejs and mysql 
and that's worked and the data inserted but the problem the page still reloaded and never stop after i clicking on submit button and sending the same value more than one time to the database

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var  server = require('http').createServer(app);
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      database: 'chmult',
      user: 'root',
      password: '',
    });
users = [];
connections = [];


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/');

});



app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

/**bodyParser.json(options)
 * Parses the text as JSON and exposes the resulting object on req.body.
 */
app.use(bodyParser.json());
connection.connect();

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user.username)
    connection.query("Insert into tesko (username) VALUES ('"+req.body.user.username+"')")



});



app.listen(3231);
console.log('Example app listening at port:3000');
```

the html code

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="user[username]">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>







</html>
```

Comment: Blindly concatenating user input into an SQL query is begging for an injection attack. **DO NOT DO THIS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the callback on `connection.query` and you don't do anything with `res`

Try this

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user.username)
    connection.query("INSERT INTO tesko (username) VALUES ('"+req.body.user.username+"')", function(err){
        return res.send('Done');
    })
});
```

See here:

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_insert.asp

As noted in comment of question, this is ripe for SQL injection, and you should use parameters instead:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.user.username)
    connection.query("INSERT INTO tesko SET ? ", {username: req.body.username}, function(err){
        return res.send('Done');
    })
});
```

Comment: Please avoid referencing w3schools (for anything). Instead, reference the relevant, official documentation [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/master/Readme.md).

Comment: I would have, but unfortunately nowhere in the *official* docs is a clear, concise example of what the OP was trying to achieve.